# React checkbox boolean value in ajax put request / Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox, reactjs

This is my first foray into React.

I'm working on a checkbox component that I want to use twice.  This is the parent component:

```
    var SearchItem = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
            return { data: [] };
        },
        render: function(){
            return <div className='searchItem'>
                        <p>{this.props.data.date}</p>
                        <a href={this.props.data.url} target='_blank' {this.props.data.title}</a>
                        <p>{this.props.data.company}</p>
                        <p>{this.props.data.description}</p>    
                        <form>
                            <CheckBox value = {this.props.data.saved} id = {this.props.data.id} text = 'Save' />
                            <CheckBox value = {this.props.data.applied} id = {this.props.data.id} text = 'Applied' />
                        </form>
                    </div>
        }
    });
```

What I want to do here is make an ajax put request, passing a boolean value for Saved or Applied, depending on the context.  This is the checkbox component:

```
    var CheckBox = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
            return { data: [] }
        },
        handleClick: function(e){
        $.ajax({
                data: // not sure what to do here,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/searches/' + this.props.id + '.json',
                type: 'put',
                context: this,
                success: function(data, status, xhr){
                this.setState({
                    //  not sure what to do here
                });
                }.bind(this),
                error: function(xhr, status, err){  
                    console.log("whoops, something didn't work:"),
                    console.log(status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this)
            });
        },
        render: function(){
            var value = this.props.value;
            return (
                <label><input type='checkbox' className='checkBox' defaultChecked={value} onClick={this.handleClick} />{this.props.text}</label>
            )
        }
    });
```

I want the data value to look like this: { saved: *boolean* } or { applied: *boolean* } depending on the whether this is the Saved checkbox or the Applied checkbox.

Problems:

1) Not sure how to set the data value dynamically, so I can reuse this component.

2) This checkbox boolean trick '$('input:checkbox').is('checked') ? true : false' doesn't work because '$('input:checkbox')' returns every checkbox on the page.

3) I suppose data in the success callback should my updated model, and I'll need to grab whatever attribute I just updated in order to set the component's state.  Right?  But again, I'll need to determine *which* checkbox it is.

EDIT:

This is what the CheckBox component ended up looking like.

```
var CheckBox = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
            return { data: [] }
        },
        componentDidMount: function(){
            this.setState({
                checked: this.props.value
            });
        },
        handleClick: function(e){
            var ajaxData = {}
            ajaxData[this.props.attribute] = !this.state.checked;
            $.ajax({
                data: ajaxData,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/searches/' + this.props.id + '.json',
                type: 'put',
                context: this,
                success: function(data, status, xhr){
                    this.setState({
                        checked: data[this.props.attribute]
                    });
                }.bind(this),
                error: function(xhr, status, err){  
                    console.log(status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this)
            });
        },
        render: function(){
            return (
                <label><input type='checkbox' checked={this.state.checked} className='checkBox' onClick={this.handleClick} />{this.props.text}</label>
            )
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure how to set the data value dynamically, so I can reuse this component.

What I'd do is to add a prop to the `Checkbox` component to tell the component what it attribute it represents.

So the parent would create the `Checkbox` like

`<CheckBox value = {this.props.data.saved} id = {this.props.data.id} text = 'Save' attribute='saved' />`

Then on the `Checkbox` you can do

```
handleClick: function(e){
    var ajaxData = {};
    ajaxData[this.props.attribute] = this.state.checked;
    $.ajax({
        data: ajaxData,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/searches/' + this.props.id + '.json',
        type: 'put',
        context: this,
        success: function(data, status, xhr){
        this.setState({
            //  not sure what to do here
        });
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err){  
            console.log("whoops, something didn't work:"),
            console.log(status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });
},
```

> This checkbox boolean trick '$('input:checkbox').is('checked') ? true : false' doesn't work because '$('input:checkbox')' returns every checkbox on the page.

The React way to do that is to keep track of the checked in a state variable not relaying on jQuery to trigger it. Specially if you want to create a reusable component.

```
var CheckBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { data: [] }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.setState({ checked: this.props.value });
    },

    toggleChecked: function() {
      this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    },

    render: function(){
        var value = this.props.value;
        return (
            <label><input type='checkbox' onChange = {this.toggleChecked} className='checkBox' defaultChecked={value} onClick={this.handleClick} />{this.props.text}</label>
        )
    }
});
```

Watch out, I removed the handleClick just so you focused on the changes made :). You can take the code from the first answer and put it in the second and all should work.

> I suppose data in the success callback should my updated model, and I'll need to grab whatever attribute I just updated in order to set the component's state. Right? But again, I'll need to determine which checkbox it is.

Finally since you now have the checked attribute in a state variable in your callback you can simply do `this.setState({ checked: response.checked })` or whatever name your response come with.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for input.  One thing though, it doesn't seem like this function is working: 'toggleChecked: function(){
   console.log('state is:' + this.state.checked)
   this.setState({
    checked: !this.state.checked
   });
   console.log('state is now:' + this.state.checked)
  }'.    It logs the same boolean value for both.

Comment: Try replacing `checked` with `isChecked` in `componentDidMount` and `toggleChecked`. I wasn't sure if the word `checked` was allowed.

Comment: checked is allowed, but this setState function isn't doing what it should